# Differences between Stata teffects psmatch and nnmatch?

Tags: stata, matching

I am using Stata 13 to analyse some observational data and a treatment. I came across an abundance of possible ways to estimate treatment effects with Stata. Let me just show you two options below (excluding the popular psmatch2, pscore  and attn etc.).

```
use "http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/cattaneo2.dta", clear

global treat mbsmoke
global match mmarried mage medu fbaby
global ylist bweight

*Option 1: teffects psmatch
teffects psmatch ($ylist) ($treat $match, logit), atet

*Option 2: teffects nnmatch
teffects nnmatch ($ylist $match) ($treat), atet
```

I use the Cattaneo sample, which offers some material on the mother's habit to smoke (treatment), birth weight of a child (endogenous variable), and a few factors to match (here randomly selected marriage status of the mother, mother's age, and first baby). I always calculate the average treatment effect on the treated and match at least one nearest neighbour.

I tried to specify the commands as similar as possible - but the outcomes differ a bit:   -245.711 vs. -239.2433.

**I have a few questions:** First and foremost, why do the results differ? When should one use psmatch and when nnmatch? And, why can I specify nnmatch to exactly match on some criteria (via ematch) and why is that not the case for psmatch?

Crossposted at: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1323628-differences-between-stata-teffects-psmatch-and-nnmatch

Comment: There is a statistical question here underneath the Stata, but it's possibly too hard for a non-Stata user interested in matching to follow this. I am a Stata user, but I don't do this kind of thing. I have to suggest that Statalist is a better forum, although I know that your most recent question is at the time of writing not answered there. I am not voting to close, as someone may bite.

Comment: Thank you Nick. You have answered many questions of mine before and I always value your input.  I do not want to crosspost and I felt that this post is at home here - though I understand your concern. Let me suggest that I will keep this post running here for some more time. If you indeed suggest I should close it, I will however comply.

Comment: It's your choice. If you get an answer here, excellent. Cross-posting is allowed but courtesy just implies that you are explicit about it. (_Simultaneous_ cross-posting to _several_ forums is often regarded poorly, but you are not doing that.) So, if you decide to post on Statalist, tell them about this, and _vice versa_.

Comment: Both are _matching estimators_, but the methods are not equivalent. Therefore, the results are not necessarily equivalent. A good read at the [[TE] Treatment Effects](www.stata.com/manuals13/te/) manual (if not done yet, e.g. pp. 43-44), specially the introductory part, should help dissipate doubts.

Comment: Maybe the confusion arises because both commands have a `nneighbor(#) ` option, but this only specifies the number of matches per observation. The _method_ used in matching differs for both commands. `teffects nnmatch` uses a "distance" metric, while `teffects psmatch` uses estimated predicted probabilities of treatment.

Comment: Thank you! I read up on the functionality - and yes indeed I just assumed both were basically the same given nneighbor(#). But why can't one exactly match on certain criteria with psmatch? Is it impossible?